# During PostBack JavaScript losing its functionality

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have one GridView which has one CheckBox and three TextBoxes in its template column.
The logic is, when I check the CheckBox, the corresponding TextBoxes should get enabled. If I uncheck the CheckBox, then the corresponding TextBoxes should get disabled. I have written  JavaScript for this functionality.

Everything is working fine, but in that page I have one DropDownList too. When I change the DropDownList value, the page gets PostBack and at that time I lost the JavaScript functionality, i.e. the enabled TextBoxes in the GridView gets disabled. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Show the markup amd javascript. Does the GridView placed in an UpdatePanel?

Comment: when are you adding the function on the check box? on which event?

Comment: @OneHalfTrackMindMan: Yes. I placed the GridView inside an Update Panel and My Page has 12 DropDownList. When I change any one of the DropDownList's SelectedValue, The TextBoxes in the GridView return backs to their original state. ie. Disabled...

Comment: Change your drop down from a postback to an ajax call. You won't regret it.

Comment: How you subscribe for checkbox event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After every post back in the update panel **you need to reinitialize your javascript**, because as you understand the struct of the html has change and javascript runs on the previous one that not exist after the update panel updates. Microsoft gives a functionality to do that as follow.

This is javascript lines.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
    prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

    function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {      
    }

    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
      // here initialize again your javascript
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Do I want to copy and paste the JavaScript function again there?

Comment: @Thevan I suggest to add your javascript inside a function called initialize or something like that, and call it 2 times, one time when page load (as you do now) and one time after the EndREquest in the function I show you

Comment: @Aristos and thevan I have the same problem as this, can you show me an example how did you call the 2 functions? is it on the ASPX or the C#? Thanks in advance

Comment: @wolfQueen This is on the aspx page, its javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Use the RowCreated event for the ASP Grid to add the client function on the check box, this way the client function will stay on each postback

Answer (score 0):

You must register your javascript at each postback for it to run, by using the `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` method: [here's](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=200) an example (edited for article in english, sorry :p).

Answer (score -1):

Use auto post back with check box to enable disable text box from server side code. This will update the view state and so it will be maintained on select change. Use these inside UpdatePanel for ajax. Alternatively, you can add drop down into updatepanel as well, so that select change does not affect other page elements.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript is working on DOM. When page gets PostBack values from ViewState are written to DOM and overwrites your JavaScript changes. You should store state of checkboxes in persistent way ie. jQuery data() or hiddenfield and after PostBack write changes back to DOM.

Comment: jquery data() is not persisted across post backs